# All my blocks disappeared

Tags: magento2

I'm a little new to Magento, hoping for some help ... running Magento 2.1.13, public site is [here](https://shop.alexslemonade.org/)

I just upgraded an extension, and somehow now all of the **blocks** are missing: **banner**, **footer**, etc.  I've cleared caches, re-compiled, disabled and re-enabled the theme, re-deployed static content.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Sam Nelson

Comment: which extension did you upgrade?

Comment: Figured it out, more or less -- something to do with no longer passing in a $scopeConfig into a constructor.  I think.